# how to delete 600 GBs of small files?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

This was an interview question, they did not tell any information about the files, ie: extension, hidden files?, location (stored in single directory or a directory tree), so my first reaction to this question was:

```
rm -fr *
```

oh no, wait, should be:

```
rm -fr -- *
```

Then I realize that the above command would not remove hidden files successfully and quite frankly directories like `.` and `..` might interfere, my second and final thought was a ShellScript that uses `find`.

```
find -depth -type f -delete
```

I'm not sure if this is the right way of doing it, I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not as obvious as it seems:

http://linuxnote.net/jianingy/en/linux/a-fast-way-to-remove-huge-number-of-files.html

Comment: I found it quite impressive how fast rsync could be, although, I have not been able to delete a file successfully with rsync, perhaps I should do a little more research on this subject. For the record the following command is the one I'm using to make tests `rsync -a --delete test/`, any suggestions?

Comment: you probably need something like `mkdir -p /tmp/empty; rsync -a --delete /tmp/empty/. test/.`